# Using jquery to do an image find and replace with a mouseenter on another <div>

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have two images, each in a separate div.  When I do a mouseenter on the first image, I need the second image to change in the other div.

The image that changes comes after the image with the mouseenter in the code.  So far, I have

```
<script>

var Read1 = $("img[src$='/reading1.png']");
var Read2 = $("img[src$='reading2.png']");


$('#shelf-1').mouseenter(function() {
$('#read').find(Read1).replaceWith(Read2)
});
</script>
```

I am very new to using jquery, so I feel lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you possibly use http://jsfiddle.net to recreate the issue?  The code you've posted makes answering this question difficult.  At least add the html for the two images if you could ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put ids on your image tags instead of your divs so that it's easier to access them.  Then its at simple as

```
$('#read1').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#read2').attr('src', 'reading2.png');
});
```

If you are sold on your solution, the reason it isn't working is because the variables Read1 and Read2 are incorrect.  Read1 should be the string selector you are looking for and Read2 should be the proper html you want to replace the element with. The following should work:

```
<script>
    var Read1 = "img[src$='/reading1.png']";
    var Read2 = "<img src='path/to/reading2.png'>";

    $('#shelf-1').mouseenter(function() {
       $('#read').find(Read1).replaceWith(Read2)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what if the image Read2 is in another div or id than Read1?

Comment: ids are unique across the page, so it won't matter if read2 is in a different div to read1.  It is generally better to access elements directly by id then to traverse the DOM structure looking for that element by some other attribute like you are attempting to do.

Comment: This soultion will not work I suppose. Read1 is not a html element. So find(Read1) won't fetch anything and will not be replaced with anything. Did you check with this code/

Comment: Find also works with selectors, which was put in before searching with an element. See http://api.jquery.com/find/. And yep I checked it, so it should work.  The only thing you need to do is put in the proper path to reading2.png.  If it doesn't work, post your html and I'll see how different it is to mine.

Comment: Hey, it works great.  thanks for the explanation as well, I've started reading through everything at jquery.com, but it can get a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#shelf-1').mouseenter(function() {
$('#read').html("<img src=\"reading2.png\"> </img>");
});
```

Since you are literally creating a img tag in Read2 thought I could just do it on the fly. 
Works for me. Check it out.

Comment: that totally works.  thanks a ton.  I have one question, is it possible to combine .find() and .replaceWith()

Comment: Yes you can. I've updated my answer with details of why your code wasn't working.

Comment: `$('body').find('#read > img').replaceWith(Read2);` I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Not necessarily. That will find all image tags under the #read div, when he has specifically asked for one that ends with "/reading1.png".

Comment: Also, using `.html` will replace everything in the #read div, so if there are any other tags that are children of #read, they will be removed as well.

Comment: The question did not demand particular image tag to be replaced with. It just said Replace an image in one div when mouseenter event occurs on the other. If the question had been 'find that particular image tag inside one div and during mouseenter event change one particular image in another div tag' then this solution is not suitable otherwise I don't see why it is wrong.

Comment: I think you need to look at the question a bit more closely.  OP says "I need **the** second image to change in **the** other div". Not **an** image.   Then in his code example, he specifies what he is trying to find - `var Read1 = $("img[src$='/reading1.png']");`.

Comment: Its a bit ambiguous. The OP initially mentions "first image" and not first image in the first div just first image and then mentioned second image. I thought it to be another image.